# Problem With WPF C# App Spawning Two Main Windows

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, visual-studio

I've been working on this app for the last few days and suddenly this super weird problem starting happening where 2 of my primary windows starting spawning during run time. I've searched for 3 hours and can't find where or why this is happening. If you want to show a stranger some love, can you help me find why this is happening?

My project is located here (requires .NET 4):

http://www.kirkouimet.com/files/development/Listen.zip

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In App.xaml you have `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` and in App.xaml.cs you have `MainWindow = new MainWindow()` and then `MainWindow.Show()`. Just remove the one in App.xaml and you're good to go.

Comment: I love you.

Any comments on my code structure and how I can improve it?

Comment: Sorry, I have not looked at your code in details, so I can't comment on it. I focused only on figuring out the actual problem.

Comment: 7 Years later and this helped me, too!